# SQL Command help in VBA MSAccess

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run an update query command on a form when certain statements are true. I am updating the field from a variable. This is what I have so far to run the SQL but it does not seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Any suggestions?

```
fldval = Me.AdvHours

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                    "SET dbo_employees.advhours = '" & _
                    fldval & "'" & _
                    "WHERE ((dbo_employees.empid)=" & EmpID & "));"
```

Comment: dbo_ suggests that you are using an SQL Server database with MS Access front end, is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra closing `)` - missing space before `WHERE` (thats prolly ok)

All the parentheses are unnecessary, Access just has a fetish for them.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                    "SET dbo_employees.advhours='" & _
                    fldval & "' " & _
                    "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & EmpID & ";"
```